# How do I recall multiple images saved in storage in my web page?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I've saved in MYSQL database and in my laravel storage two images created by a form of my webpage. I just wanna recall all images saved in the storage and show all them in my webpage. I've used this in my createcar.blade.php page:

`<img src="{{Storage::url(img)}}" alt="img">`

but it doesn't work

This is the createcar.blade.php part form page:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row py-3" style="justify-content:center">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form_main">
                @if ($errors->any())
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <ul>
                            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                @endif
                <h4 class="heading"><strong>Compile </strong> form! <span> 
             </span></h4>
                <div class="form">
                    <form action="{{route('submit')}}" method="post" id="contactFrm" name="contactFrm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                        <input type="text" required="" placeholder="Name Car" value="{{old('name')}}" name="name" class="txt">
                        <input type="file" name="img" placeholder="Image"
                               value="{{old('img')}}">
                        <textarea placeholder="Features Vehicle"
                                  name="message" value="{{old('message')}}" type="text" class="txt_3"> </textarea>
                        <input type="submit" value="Add" name="submit" class="txt2">
                    </form>
                    <img src="{{Storage::url(img)}}" alt="img"> //this is the code i've used to recall images from storage
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the file CarsController.php

```
  <?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
 use App\Http\Requests\CarsRequest;


 class CarsController extends Controller
 {
 public function submit(CarsRequest $req){

    $nome = $req->input('name');
    $messaggio = $req->input('message');
    $img = $req->file('img')->store('public/img');

    $dati = compact('nome', 'messaggio', 'img');

        DB::table('cars')->insert(

        [
        'name' => $nome,
        'message' => $messaggio,
        'img' => $img,
        ]);

    return redirect(route('carthankyou'));

  }

  public function carthankyou() {
    return view('contacts.carthankyou'); 

 }
```

Comment: So show us the controller where you call the model to get the info about where and what the images are called

Comment: Added Controller file

Answer (score 1):

You should find images in database

```
public function carthankyou() {
    $cars = DB::table('cars')->get();
    return view('contacts.carthankyou', ['cars' => $cars]); 
}
```

and show images like this

```
@foreach($cars as $car)
    <img src="{{Storage::url($car->img)}}" alt="img">
@endforeach
```

also you can add user_id field and show only current user cars

Comment: I've tryed your solution but It returns me this error: Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Undefined variable: cars

Comment: oh, you should do it in method where you call createcar.blade.php providerit pls